# How to modify element in a list from a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a list of 4 integer lists, each with 4 elements.

How can I modify an element in a particular list without modifying all other elements of the same index number in the other 3 lists?

What I've been trying to do, for example, is modifying the first list at the first position through the following code:

```
longList[0][0] = 1
```

What I end up getting is a list that looks like

```
[[1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0]]
```

rather than what I want:

```
[[1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
```

which is strange, considering that I only asked for the first element in the first list to be modified.

Would anyone know a way to fix this issue so that I can get the latter result rather than the former one, which my code is outputting?

Maybe it's a problem in the way I've been setting up the list? (which is as follows):

```
longList = [[0] * 4] * 4
```

Here's the most simplified version of my code issue:

```
longList = [[0] * 4] * 27

print(longList)
longList[0][1] = 1
print(longList)  #outputs the result I don't want
```

Thanks.

Comment: kindly share your code. I do same thing and i got  `[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`

Comment: @Mehmaam Sorry about that, I updated my answer with my code.

Comment: Playing off of @NewEnglandcottontail 's comment, conisder the following: `ll = [[0] * 4] * 4; new_ll = [[0] * 4] * 4` => `ll[0] is ll[1]` will return True, versus `new_ll[0] is ll[0]` returns False, because new references are created. This also highlights the difference between `==` and `is`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this out

```py
longList = [[0] * 4] * 4
tmp = longList[0].copy()
tmp[0] = 1
longList[0] = tmp
print(longList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! While your method works fine, it was an error in choosing to multiply the lists by a constant, as some other members kindly pointed out.